# Как я могу выровнять текст, который не умещается в первой строке, по правому краю в CSS, как это делают в поэзии?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я добавляю стихи на свой сайт. Проблема в том, что при уменьшении размера экрана строки стихотворения рвутся.
Я хочу показать часть строки, которая идет после разрыва строки, как в сборниках стихов, когда длина строки стиха не соответствует ширине страницы.

Вот пример:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the
                           lazy dog
```

Первая строка выровнена по левому краю, вторая - по правому. (Конечно, это будет происходить только на маленьких экранах.)

Есть ли способ сделать это повторяемым?
Это не разовое мероприятие; Я пытаюсь создать стандарт с классами.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I align the text that didn't fit the first line to right in CSS, like they do in poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64770921/7394871) от участника  [@bedirhangn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7335891/bedirhangn).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64770921/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Используйте  **[text-align-last](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)**

[Поддержка браузерами](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-align-last)

```css
.box {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow:auto;
}
.box * {
  /*text-align:justify; раскомментируйте это, чтобы увидеть эффект `justify`, тоже неплохо */
  text-align-last: right;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div><br>
  <div>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771215/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Существует псевдоэлемент CSS для выбора первой строки текста, который вы можете использовать здесь:

`::first-line`

Update: несмотря на то, что селектор поддерживается во всех основных браузерах, похоже, что некоторые браузеры не позволяют применять выравнивание текста с этим селектором. Так что, это ненадежное кроссбраузерное решение (пока?), Я оставлю его здесь на случай, если оно кому-то пригодится или станет действительным в будущем.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
#wrapper span::first-line {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
  <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</span>
  <span>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</span>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771095/7394871) от участника  [@DBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650337/dbs).</sub>